# making a loop creating new vectors in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset of 70 patients. At 6 different datapoints 2 laboratory values were obtained that probably correlate with each other. Here you can see some extracted data

```
id     w2_crp     w2_alb    w6_crp     w6_alb     w10_crp     w10_alb
001     1.2       35         1.1        38         0.5         39
002      10       27          0.5         42.5      0.5         40
003     2.4       30         1.7        30          1.2         32
004      0.5      37.4       0.7         38.2        0.5        35.5
```

For each patient I want to plot crp values on x-axis and albumin values on y axis at corresponding timepoints.

I made these vectors for 10 first IDs:

```
vec1 <- pull(df, w2_crp)
vec2 <- pull(df, w2_alb)
...

crp1 <- (c(first(vec1)), (first(vec3)), (first(vec5)))
```

and similar vectors for albumin and plotted them normally with
`plot_ly(df, x ~crp1, y ~alb1, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")`
but this is obviously very tedious. Do you have any ideas how to automize creating vectors and plotting them against each other with a for loop? I tried but constantly got errors... I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: Hello Jagoda, can you add some extra detail on you question? I can't guess some points, like how do you extract crp1, or if te patients in the dataset are represented by id, or how do you select 10 patients. Also i guess that the plotly code should be `plot_ly(df, x= ~crp1, y= ~alb1, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the number in the column name is the timepoint. If so, you could do this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

#example data
dat <- read_table("id     w2_crp     w2_alb    w6_crp     w6_alb     w10_crp     w10_alb
001     1.2       35         1.1        38         0.5         39
002      10       27          0.5         42.5      0.5         40
003     2.4       30         1.7        30          1.2         32
004      0.5      37.4       0.7         38.2        0.5        35.5")

#make each timepoint a row and each group a column
new_dat <- dat |>
  pivot_longer(-id, names_pattern="\\w(\\d+)_(\\w+)", 
               names_to = c("time", "type")) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value) 

new_dat
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>    id    time    crp   alb
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 001   2       1.2  35  
#>  2 001   6       1.1  38  
#>  3 001   10      0.5  39  
#>  4 002   2      10    27  
#>  5 002   6       0.5  42.5
#>  6 002   10      0.5  40  
#>  7 003   2       2.4  30  
#>  8 003   6       1.7  30  
#>  9 003   10      1.2  32  
#> 10 004   2       0.5  37.4
#> 11 004   6       0.7  38.2
#> 12 004   10      0.5  35.5

#plot data
new_dat|>
  ggplot(aes(crp, alb, color = time))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~id, scales = "free")
```

[image]